# is it ever valid to use MOVF with a single operand ? If so, what is the advantage?

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip

I have come across a couple of examples of MOVF being used without the second operand, for example:

```
;incorrect context restore
MOVF  STATUS_Temp,w
MOVWF STATUS
MOVF  W_Temp ;this may change the Z bit    <------ !! MOVF with single operand !!
             ;in the Status register

;good context restore
MOVF  STATUS_Temp,w
MOVWF STATUS
SWAPF W_Temp,f ;swap in place
SWAPF W_Temp,w ;swap with Wreg destination
```

(sample taken from the PICKIT2 LPC board user guide)

A quick experiment in MPLAB SIM suggests that the second 'destination' operand is optional and defaults to the working register. i.e.

```
MOVF  W_Temp,w
```

Is this one of those coding 'features' that, while strictly possible, is just another way of making code less readable ? Or is there more to it than that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is important only when we are leaveing the **interrupt** rutine, so we must to restore all ALU flags correctlly!

```
    ...   
    MOVF  STATUS_Temp,w ;Restore ALU flags
    MOVWF STATUS 
    MOVF  W_Temp,w      ;Restore the w register and also affect to the Zero flag
    RETFIE              ;Exit from interrupt
```

Instruction `MOVF  W_Temp` should copy back the content of w file register as we expect, but from the other side also affect to the Zero flag which is part of STATUS file register. So we cant use it if we want correctly restore the privius Zero flag state when we leaving the interrupt.

```
    ...
    MOVF  STATUS_Temp,w ;Restore ALU flags
    MOVWF STATUS 
    SWAPF W_Temp,f
    SWAPF W_Temp,w      ;Restore the w register  
    RETFIE              ;Exit from interrupt
```

In this second case the SWAPF (we perform double swap so the content of w register is restored back correctly) instruction doesn't affect to the Zero flag so it is safe to use it.

**EDIT:**

If you was read the Microchip datasheet than than you can red that the instrution `MOVF` has also one (bit size) operand.

So you can write in MPLAB IDE.

```
MOVF  W_Temp, W    ;Copy W_Temp to W and set Zero flag if value is 0, otherwise clear.
MOVF  W_Temp, F    ;Copy W_Temp back to W_Temp  and set Zero flag if value is 0, otherwise clear.
MOVF  W_Temp       ;Is equal MOVF  W_Temp, F beacuse the defailt operant is F (1)
```

Using `MOVF  W_Temp, F` (or `MOVF  W_Temp`) is usefull if we wont to test the zero content of  `W_Temp` file register and not change the content of w register.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that my question was not about context restore, this was just one example I found where MOVF is being used with only a single argument. I picked this example because it came from a document written by Microchip themselves, so (presumably!) carries some authority.

Comment: @thermalCat: Your example can be foud in Microchip documents and talk about restoring interrupts! So `MOVF` instructions is always
 valid and very usefull, except in case when wa are restoring the interrupt in that case use double `SWAPF` instead!

Comment: @thermalCat: check my upper EDIT to clarify.

Comment: Ah, I should have thought to check a datasheet sooner. Thanks for your help